# Controls overlaps other controls and need more space

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

My listview when new items are added overlaps the buttons. The buttons seems to have same place on the center of application. I would love to have them at the bottom. From the other hand listview should expand to the buttons and then scroll should appear. Last thing is the listview itself overlaps top part of controls and there is need to make more space i suppose (i highlited it on black on the picture. How can i fix that? Below screnshoot how it looks at the moment and current code as well. Thanks.

[image]

**Full xaml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MobileAppXamarinForms.Views.Order.OrderModifyPage"
             Title="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderId, StringFormat='Numer zamówienia: {0}'}">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="4" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderId, StringFormat='NUMER ZAMÓWIENIA: {0}'}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Gray" Grid.Column="0" Padding="30,1,1,1" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                <Label Text="                " Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                <Label Text="KLIENT:" FontSize="15"  VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedClient.Value, StringFormat='{0}'}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Gray" Grid.Column="3" 
                       Padding="5,1,1,1" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="NA DZIEŃ:" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <DatePicker Date="{Binding SelectedTargetDate, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="dd.MM.yyyy" 
                            Grid.Column="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            </Grid>

            <Grid ColumnSpacing="4" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Text="BUTLA:" FontSize="15" TextColor="Gray" Grid.Column="0" Padding="30,1,1,1" FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Picker Title="BUTLA" ItemsSource="{Binding Bottles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBottle, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Id}" FontSize="15" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                <Label Text="                " Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                <Label Text="ILOŚĆ:" FontSize="15"  VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                <Entry Placeholder="Ilość" Text="{Binding SelectedAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="5" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            </Grid>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Fill">
                <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="Fill">
                    <!--Listview section-->
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                    <ListView.Header>
                        <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="Nazwa butli" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="0"   FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                            <Label Text="Pełna?" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                            <Label Text="Ilość" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                            <Label Text="Kwota" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ListView.Header>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="{Binding BottleTypeName}" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="{Binding BottleIsFilled}" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="{Binding Amount}" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text ="{Binding Price}" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                    <!--Buttons section-->
                    <Grid ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        
                        <Button Text="Dodaj butlę"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                Command="{Binding SaveBottleCommand}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Text="Usuń butlę"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="MediumVioletRed"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                Command="{Binding RemoveBottleCommand}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Text="Ok"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="Red"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                Command="{Binding ClearFormCommand}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        <Button Text="Ok"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                Command="{Binding ClearFormCommand}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**EDIT 1:**

[image]

**Current code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MobileAppXamarinForms.Views.Order.OrderModifyPage"
             Title="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderId, StringFormat='Numer zamówienia: {0}'}">


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <!-- ********** COL 0 | ROW 0 ********** -->
            <Grid Column="0" Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderId, StringFormat='NUMER ZAMÓWIENIA: {0}'}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Gray" 
                       Grid.Column="0" Padding="30,1,1,1" FontAttributes="None" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="KLIENT:" FontSize="15"  VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding SelectedClient.Value, StringFormat='{0}'}" FontSize="16" TextColor="Gray" Grid.Column="2" FontAttributes="None" VerticalOptions="Center"/>


                <Label Text="NA DZIEŃ:" Grid.Column="3" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <DatePicker Date="{Binding SelectedTargetDate, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="dd.MM.yyyy" Grid.Column="4"/>

            </Grid>
                
            <!-- ********** COL 0 | ROW 1 ********** -->
            <Grid Column="0" Row="1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Text="BUTLA:" FontSize="15" TextColor="Gray" Grid.Column="0" Padding="30,1,1,1" 
                       FontAttributes="None" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                <Picker Title="BUTLA" ItemsSource="{Binding Bottles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBottle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Id}" FontSize="15"  
                        VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>


                <Label Text="                " Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                <Label Text="ILOŚĆ:" FontSize="15"  VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>


                <Entry Placeholder="Ilość" Text="{Binding SelectedAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric" MaxLength="5" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
            </Grid>

            <!-- ********** COL 0 | ROW 2 ********** -->
            <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Column="0" Row="2">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
                        <RowDefinition Grid.ColumnSpan="1" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <!--Listview section-->
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                    <ListView.Header>
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="White" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Label Text="Nazwa butli" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="0"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                            <Label Text="Pełna?" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="1"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                            <Label Text="Ilość" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="2"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                            <Label Text="Kwota" HorizontalOptions="Fill"  Grid.Column="3"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ListView.Header>

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text ="{Binding BottleTypeName}" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text ="{Binding BottleIsFilled}" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="2" Text ="{Binding Amount}" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="3" Text ="{Binding Price}" BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke" HorizontalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
            </Grid>

            <!-- ********** COL 0 | ROW 3 ********** -->
                <Grid BackgroundColor="White"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3">
                    <Button Text="Dodaj butlę" Grid.Row="1"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                Command="{Binding SaveBottleCommand}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                    <Button Text="Usuń butlę"  Grid.Row="1"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="MediumVioletRed"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                Command="{Binding RemoveBottleCommand}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                    <Button Text="Ok"  Grid.Row="1"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="Red"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                Command="{Binding ClearFormCommand}" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                    <Button Text="Ok"  Grid.Row="1"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                Margin="20"
                                BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"
                                TextColor="White"
                                FontSize="20"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                Command="{Binding ClearFormCommand}" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                </Grid>


            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**EDIT 3:**

[image]

Comment: your ListView and buttons are both contained in a Grid with no RowDefintions, so both will occupy the same row and overlap.  You need to place each one in its own row

Comment: @Jason could you post as an answer? And wehat about top part ? Without listview top part of this (i mean controls above the listview are shown fine, when i placed listview there became squezeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would love to have them at the bottom.

If you want to place button at the bottom , just set `VerticalOptions="End"` for Grid.

> listview itself overlaps top part of controls and there is need to make more space.

You can use Margin to add space between control and ListView.

I modify your code, you can take a look:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Padding="30,1,1,1"
                FontAttributes="None"
                FontSize="16"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderId, StringFormat='NUMER ZAMÓWIENIA: {0}'}"
                TextColor="Gray"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="                " />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="2"
                FontSize="15"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Text="KLIENT:"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="3"
                Padding="5,1,1,1"
                FontAttributes="None"
                FontSize="16"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="{Binding SelectedClient.Value, StringFormat='{0}'}"
                TextColor="Gray"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="4"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="NA DZIEŃ:"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <DatePicker
                Grid.Column="5"
                Date="{Binding SelectedTargetDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Format="dd.MM.yyyy"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Padding="30,1,1,1"
                FontAttributes="None"
                FontSize="15"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="BUTLA:"
                TextColor="Gray"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Picker
                Title="BUTLA"
                Grid.Column="1"
                FontSize="15"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Bottles}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding Id}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBottle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="                " />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="3"
                FontSize="15"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Text="ILOŚĆ:"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Entry
                Grid.Column="4"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Keyboard="Numeric"
                MaxLength="5"
                Placeholder="Ilość"
                Text="{Binding SelectedAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--  Listview section  -->
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="1"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Nazwa butli"
                            TextColor="White" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="1"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Pełna?"
                            TextColor="White" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Margin="1"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Ilość"
                            TextColor="White" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            Margin="1"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Kwota"
                            TextColor="White" />
                    </Grid>
                </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding BottleTypeName}" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding BottleIsFilled}" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding Amount}" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="3"
                                    BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding Price}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <!--  Buttons section  -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="End">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
                    Command="{Binding SaveBottleCommand}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Dodaj butlę"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill" />
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    BackgroundColor="MediumVioletRed"
                    Command="{Binding RemoveBottleCommand}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Usuń butlę"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    Command="{Binding ClearFormCommand}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Ok"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"
                    Command="{Binding ClearFormCommand}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Ok"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>


        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

**Update:**

> 1. Those items are cutted how to make more space for those item's texts?

Setting Picker `ColumnDefinitions width=80` or higher.

> 2. How to make this more to the left?
>    Try to set Label   `HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"`

> 3. When i select item in listview i only see colored orange line - how to make full item select?

Delete ListView ViewCell grid and Lable  `BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke"`

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Padding="30,1,1,1"
                FontAttributes="None"
                FontSize="16"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="{Binding SelectedOrder.OrderId, StringFormat='NUMER ZAMÓWIENIA: {0}'}"
                TextColor="Gray"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Grid.Column="1"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="                " />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="2"
                FontSize="15"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Text="KLIENT:"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="3"
                Padding="5,1,1,1"
                FontAttributes="None"
                FontSize="16"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="{Binding SelectedClient.Value, StringFormat='{0}'}"
                TextColor="Gray"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="4"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                Text="NA DZIEŃ:"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <DatePicker
                Grid.Column="5"
                Date="{Binding SelectedTargetDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Format="dd.MM.yyyy"
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label
                Grid.Column="0"
                Padding="30,1,1,1"
                FontAttributes="None"
                FontSize="15"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="BUTLA:"
                TextColor="Gray"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Picker
                Title="BUTLA"
                Grid.Column="1"
                FontSize="15"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Bottles}"
                SelectedIndex="{Binding Id}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBottle, Mode=TwoWay}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="2"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="                " />
            <Label
                Grid.Column="3"
                FontSize="15"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Text="ILOŚĆ:"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Entry
                Grid.Column="4"
                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Keyboard="Numeric"
                MaxLength="5"
                Placeholder="Ilość"
                Text="{Binding SelectedAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--  Listview section  -->
            <ListView
                ItemsSource="{Binding bottles}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
                <ListView.Header>
                    <Grid BackgroundColor="White">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            Margin="1"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Nazwa butli"
                            TextColor="White" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Margin="1"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Pełna?"
                            TextColor="White" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Margin="1"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Ilość"
                            TextColor="White" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="3"
                            Margin="1"
                            BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Medium"
                            HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            Text="Kwota"
                            TextColor="White" />
                    </Grid>
                </ListView.Header>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                   
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding BottleTypeName}" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                   
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding BottleIsFilled}" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                   
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding Amount}" />
                                <Label
                                    Grid.Column="3"
                                   
                                    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding Price}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

            <!--  Buttons section  -->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="End">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="33.33*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Button
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
                    Command="{Binding SaveBottleCommand}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Dodaj butlę"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Fill" />
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    BackgroundColor="MediumVioletRed"
                    Command="{Binding RemoveBottleCommand}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Usuń butlę"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    Command="{Binding ClearFormCommand}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Ok"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    BackgroundColor="OrangeRed"
                    Command="{Binding ClearFormCommand}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="Ok"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
            </Grid>


        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: That's great and it works ! If possible i got additional questions - see my EDIT 3 in main post. I highlited there 3 things 1) Those items are cutted how to make more space for those item's texts? 2) How to make this more to the left? 3) When i select item in listview i only see colored orange line - how to make full item select? Many thanks anyway i am just new to xaml.

Comment: Something is wrong, when i put your updated code my listview items dissapered

Comment: any feedback Cherry? Still something wrong

Comment: @Arie please change my code listview itemsource, I use  ItemsSource="{Binding bottles}" to test at my side.

Comment: ou only changes this one regarding data binding itself? ASking just in case ;)

Comment: @Arie Yes, just replace listview itemsource ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}"

Comment: can you please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65628394/move-buttons-on-the-bottom-and-give-more-space-for-editor?noredirect=1#comment116041885_65628394

Answer (score 1):

your `ListView` and buttons are both contained in a `Grid` with no `RowDefintions`, so both will occupy the same row and overlap. You need to place each one in its own row

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and i've added at the top grid with 1 column and 4 row definitions. i specified grid col and row in locations where i commented :  <!-- ********** COL 0 | ROW 0-3 ********** --> . Nevertheless it looks as you see. Can you please help me out? Please check main post > EDIT 1 i putted there screenshoot of current state and the updated code