# Move buttons on the bottom and give more space for editor

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am struggling with two things in `xamarin forms layout`. As shown on the picture i need to make more space for `edidor control` (highlited as 1) as this will be the place for user's comment. I would like to extend it to the right (max width). Second thing is i need to move `buttons` to the bottom which i thought i could solve that by settiung `VerticalOptions="End"` in the `<Grid Grid.Row ="4"` (higlighted as 2). How can i solve both things up? Below also full xaml code.

[image]

Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MobileAppXamarinForms.Views.Order.OrderHatModifyPage"
             Title="{Binding SelectedHatOrder.OrderId, StringFormat='Numer zamówienia: {0}'}">


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <Grid Grid.Row ="0"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Padding="30,1,1,1"
                    FontAttributes="None"
                    FontSize="16"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="{Binding SelectedHatOrder.OrderId, StringFormat='NUMER ZAMÓWIENIA: {0}'}"
                    TextColor="Gray"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="                " />
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    FontSize="15"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    Text="KLIENT:"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    Padding="5,1,1,1"
                    FontAttributes="None"
                    FontSize="16"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="{Binding SelectedClient.Value, StringFormat='{0}'}"
                    TextColor="Gray"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="4"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                    Text="NA DZIEŃ:"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <DatePicker
                    Grid.Column="5"
                    Date="{Binding SelectedTargetDate, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    Format="dd.MM.yyyy"
                    HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row ="1"  Margin="5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    <!--szerokosc, aby zmiescila sie nazwa butli-->
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Padding="30,1,1,1"
                    FontAttributes="None"
                    FontSize="15"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="KWOTA:"
                    TextColor="Gray"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Entry
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    Keyboard="Numeric"
                    MaxLength="5"
                    Placeholder="Kwota"
                    Text="{Binding SelectedPrice, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    Text="                " />
                <Label
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    FontSize="15"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    Text="ILOŚĆ:"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Entry
                    Grid.Column="4"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    Keyboard="Numeric"
                    MaxLength="5"
                    Placeholder="Ilość"
                    Text="{Binding SelectedAmount, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row ="2" >
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="Start">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Padding="30,1,1,1"
                        FontAttributes="None"
                        FontSize="15"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Text="Komentarz:"
                        TextColor="Gray"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Editor
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        Keyboard="Text"
                        MaxLength="3000"
                        Placeholder="Komentarz"
                        Text="{Binding SelectedComment, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

                <Grid Grid.Row ="3"  VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Padding="30,1,1,1"
                        FontAttributes="None"
                        FontSize="15"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Text="Typ płatności:"
                        TextColor="Gray"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Picker
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Title="Typ płatności"
                        FontSize="15"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Value}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding PaymentTypes}"
                        SelectedIndex="{Binding Id}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPaymentType, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Label
                        Grid.Column="2"
                        Padding="30,1,1,1"
                        FontAttributes="None"
                        FontSize="15"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        Text="Ilość dni:"
                        TextColor="Gray"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsDaysCountVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                    <Entry
                        Grid.Column="3"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                        Keyboard="Numeric"
                        MaxLength="5"
                        Placeholder="Ilość dni"
                        IsVisible="{Binding IsDaysCountVisible, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Text="{Binding SelectedDaysCount, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </Grid>

                <!--  Buttons section  -->
                <Grid Grid.Row ="4"  VerticalOptions="End">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Button
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        BackgroundColor="DarkMagenta"
                        Command="{Binding SaveOrderCommand}"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="20"
                        Text="Zatwierdz"
                        TextColor="White"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                    <Button
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        BackgroundColor="MediumVioletRed"
                        Command="{Binding ExitCommand}"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="20"
                        Text="Anuluj"
                        TextColor="White"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: to start with, get rid of the StackLayout so that the outer grid can fill the page

Comment: @Jason first issue solved. Buttons are now bottom. How to solve second thing with comment?

Comment: set a specific height on the last row of the grid

Comment: @Jason not sure where exactly, the <Grid Grid.Row ="2" > where comments is placed - its only one row there. I was tyrying to set <ColumnDefinition Width="200" /> to <ColumnDefinition Width="500" /> without any result

Comment: I misread your question.  It's really difficult to tell what you're doing because you have so many nested layouts.  I think you could simplify it to just one or two grids.  That said, you should try setting a ColumnSpan value on the comments grid so that it spans more than one column of it's parent Grid.

Answer (score 0):

So, as @Jason said in the comments, you have to remove the `<StackLayout />` because it prevents the Grid to fill the page.

Thus, for your other issue, I tried to reproduce it.
I've found that if you change the `HorizontalOptions` of your `<Editor />` from `CenterAndExpand` to `FillAndExpand` this solves the issue (you can also remove the `HorizontalOptions` altogether).

So, instead of:

```
<Editor
         Grid.Column="1"
         HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
         Keyboard="Text"
         MaxLength="3000"
         Placeholder="Komentarz"
         Text="{Binding SelectedComment, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Try:

```
<Editor
         Grid.Column="1"
         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
         Keyboard="Text"
         MaxLength="3000"
         Placeholder="Komentarz"
         Text="{Binding SelectedComment, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Or:

```
<Editor Grid.Column="1"
         Keyboard="Text"
         MaxLength="3000"
         Placeholder="Komentarz"
         Text="{Binding SelectedComment, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

For more about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options

For good measure, you can also remove `Keyboard="Text"` since Keyboard's default value is already `Text`

I hope this solved your issue.
However, if you've got any concerns with my Answer please let me know